# Twilio - generate 6 digit random numbers

Tags: python, django, twilio

Im planning to integrate twilio for  two factor authentication in my Django application.

Now, I have installed twilio python module and sent some random messages to my number.

The next step is for me to send some random 6 digit numbers that's done in banking application or google two factor authentication.

How can I generate these numbers in my DJango application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a specific range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: You might find the [django-two-factor-auth](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) app useful. It supports Twilio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There have been some great answers to help you generate a random 6 digit string, however I just wanted to add one more suggestion.

[Authy](https://www.authy.com/developers/) is part of Twilio and provides Two Factor Authentication as a service. It supports sending codes by SMS (which goes via Twilio), generating codes in the [Authy application](https://www.authy.com/app/) and even two factor authentication without copying a code from an app/sms to your login screen with [Authy OneTouch](https://www.authy.com/product/options/#onetouch). You can implement your entire 2FA flow with just 3 API calls.

There is a tutorial on [how to use Authy with Flask](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/two-factor-authentication/python/flask), which I'm sure you could translate to Django.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Matthias' answer (I upvoted his answer);
Django provides a shortcut function for this purpose:

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

get_random_string(length=6, allowed_chars='1234567890')
```

Which is more readable and memorable.

And also if you are really concerned about randomness of this string, you may want to use [random module from pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Random.random-module.html#choice) because standard library implementations of random function in programming languages are not "random" enough for cryptographic and security related issues.

Comment: I used this solution

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.choice) to determine each digit. `choice` will give you one element from the given sequence.

The code could look like this:

```
import random
pin = ''.join(random.choice('0123456789') for _ in range(6))
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also do

```
import random
random.SystemRandom().randint(100000,999999)
```

Answer (score 0):

rand(1000, 9999); == 4 digit
rand(100000, 999999); == 6 digit

```
$client = $this->_initTwilioClient();
    $fromNo = $this->_helperPot->getTwilioPhone();
    $code = rand(1000, 9999);
    try {
        $result = $client->messages->create(
            $toNo,
            [
                'from' => $this->_helperPot->getTwilioPhone(),
                'body' => "Verification code: $code"
            ]
        );
        $output = [];
        $output['status'] = "success";
        $output['code'] = $code;
        return $output;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $output = [];
        $output['status'] = "failure";
        $output['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        return $output;
    }
```